# <PHP> Check For Epochtime then Include Files Based on User's Browser Language

Tags: php

Basically our site will check for epochtime requirement, if passed, it will show different content based on users' browser language.

I keep getting a blank page. What's wrong with this code? Please help! Trying to learn PHP here.

```
<?php
if ( $_GET['tsid'] < (time() - 10) ) {
//no match - redirect
include('index2.php
');
}
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
  switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
      //echo "PAGE FR";
      include("index_fr.php");
      break;
    case "it":
      //echo "PAGE IT";
      include("index_it.php");
      break;
    case "en":
      //echo "PAGE EN";
      include("index_en.php");
      break;        
    default:
      //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
      include("index_en.php");
      break;
  die();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be error is in

```
include('index2.php
');
```

try removing the line break after index2.php